# Laravel Nova multiple resources for same user model

Tags: laravel, admin, laravel-nova

I have a laravel + nova project.

Currently I have a USER model, with 'admin' column, with values 0 or 1.

I use this model for nova dashboard login.

Now, I want to separate admin users and normal users in nova dashboard. Like showing two Resources 1 ) Admins 2 ) Users at left side in nova dashboard.

Can I user same User model for two resources?

Currently it is showing two resources with names Admins and Users, but both opens admin list all time. Not the users list at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Admins and Users are not separate users in your case, consider using [Filters](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/filters/defining-filters.html) instead for your `User` resource.

To answer your question, if you want to stick to your implementation of 2 Nova resources for Admin and User respectively, you can add override the `index` query that is made to your Nova resource. To override this behaviour, add the following code to the Nova resource:

**App\Nova\Admin.php**

```
/**
 * Build an "index" query for the given resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('admin', 1);
}
```

And the following code to

**App\Nova\User.php**

```
/**
 * Build an "index" query for the given resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('admin', 0);
}
```

**Note:** with the above solution users can still manually navigate to `yourwebsite.test/nova/resource/admins/{id}`. Consider adding [Authorization](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/authorization.html), so users can't view admins for example (depending on your use case).

Comment: I tried your solution by overriding indexQuery. But by clicking on both, Admin and User Resource, it redirects to only Admin page ( admin index ). Not redirecting to Users.

Comment: Did you create two separate Nova resources? So `App\Nova\Admin.php` and `App\Nova\User.php`? Did you change their label? I have created these Nova resources myself and it works fine for me.

Comment: YEs, I did. Even in Left side, both Users and Admins have focus when I click on Admins. And Even I set public static $displayInNavigation = false; in Admins.php , it dissappears from left side ,still it goes to Admins.php content when I click on Users.

Comment: Did you change their label?  Can you please explain me this. I did not do this yet

Comment: Btw , I want to confirm that, I have only one "User" model.

Comment: I tried it again, having only one user. It is still working fine for me. Could you update your initial question with the contents of `App\Nova\User.php` file and the `App\Nova\Admin.php` file? With changing the label, you could change the text displayed in the navigation. But I guess they are already different? To what URL are you being navigated? To `resources/admins` or to `resources/users` when clicking the link for users or admins?